# hide one div and show another div with the click of one button

Tags: html, click, hide, show

This should be really easy for you guys but I'm a real beginner on this & need it explained simply to me. I reckon it'll also help a lot of others like me out there who are just starting out on jquery...

I'm building a site that needs to have a button on one of its pages which when clicked not only hides a div of content (for which there are loads of solutions out there) but at the same time shows a previously hidden div of content.

I need to know the jquery which'll do this & what I need to wrap around the button to set off the jquery.

Can you help me out?

Thanks,
Stu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only concerned with two div elements, `jQuery.toggle()` supports two event handler functions:

```
$('button').toggle(function(){
       $('div1').hide();
       $('div2').show();
},function(){
       $('div1').show();
       $('div2').hide();
});
```

This should work just make sure that one div has a css property `display:none` and the other div does not (is visible.)

Answer (score 0):

Inside ajax call on success you have to wirte which div you have to hide and which div you have to show.

```
$.ajax({          

       url: "Sevlet",
       type: 'POST',    
       dataType: "json",
       data:{"id":id},
       contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",       
       success: function (data) {

                  $("#div1").hide();
                  $("#div2").show();
             }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, jQuery is just a library of functions to do stuff.
So inbulit functions like hide() and show() can be used to do what you desire.I believe the documentation on jQuery for hide/show/hide_show on the links below are quite simple to understand and you should have little to no problem.  
http://api.jquery.com/hide/ 
http://api.jquery.com/show/

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

However, another way to approach the problem is to use the jQuery methods to toggle CSS properties which will cause the div elements to be shown or hidden based on css properties. I will demonstrate it for the height property, but several other's could also be used including max-height, left, right, top, bottom etc.

Altering the properties in CSS, I can see how the Div is visible or hidden

Example:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
          .Div_I_Want_To_Show{
               background: #ffe400;
               width:100%;
               height:0px;
               overflow:auto;
          }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="Div_I_Want_To_Show">
          <p>Some Random Text Here</p>
      </div>
      <button class="btn">Click to See Content</button>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
           $(".btn").click(function(){
               $('.Div_I_Want_To_Show').css('height','20em')
           });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

The fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/L7pmarzh/

And in case you wanted to know, you can animate it as well, which I guess you would want to any website, since a simple hide and show effect is not appealing to any user.

Hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: Forgot to mention, you an do the same for another element using CSS. Just make the Div's height zero on the click of the same button.
    `$('.btn').click(function({$('.the_other_div_I_forgot_about').css('height',0');});`